# Facebook Graph API to get shared links of public page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

We had investigated the `Facebook api` to get a page uploaded photos (public page ), so a common  request is :

```
https://graph.facebook.com/page id/photos/uploaded
```

Which gives all the last images from a page . But, we found out that this not returns also the shared links of a page , only photos the page itself had uploaded .

1. We would like to get also the shared links, do we need a token for that ?
2. if we do need a token ,how exactly this request would look like with the token,to get all page last data?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously the endpoint you are using only returns the uploaded photos of the page, why should it return something else?

If you want to get all links shared by a page you can use the `/page-id/links` endpoint. The documentation [1] has all the info you need regarding the tokens required to read that data.

[1] https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/page/links#read